# Delete elements from singly linked list

Tags: c, algorithm, list, pointers

i would like to delete some elements from list specified by value in function. My function doesn't work if function's 'val' is equal to my first element in list. Otherwise it works well. Any ideas?

```
struct elem {
    int val;
    struct elem *next;
};

void del(struct elem *list, int val) {
    struct elem* tmp = list;
    struct elem* prev = NULL;

    while (tmp != NULL) {
        if (tmp->val == val) {
            if (prev == NULL) {
                tmp = tmp->next;
                free(list);
                list = tmp;
            } else {
                prev->next = tmp->next;
                free(tmp);
                tmp = prev->next;
            }
        } else {
            prev = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are modifying `list` in `del()`, pass it as a double pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calling function cannot know that `list` has been updated. It will even go on referring to the same `list`, which has been deleted. Which is not good.

One solution is to pass the list as `struct elem **list`:

```
void del(struct elem **list, int val) {
    struct elem* tmp = *list;
    struct elem* prev = NULL;

    while (tmp != NULL) {
        if (tmp->val == val) {
            if (prev == NULL) {
                tmp = tmp->next;
                free(*list);
                *list = tmp;
            } else {
                prev->next = tmp->next;
                free(tmp);
                tmp = prev->next;
            }
        } else {
            prev = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: There are other solutions. You could return the new list pointer:

```
struct elem *del(struct elem *list, int val) { ... }
```

And you call it like this:

```
list = del(list, 12);
```

This solution has the disadvantage that `list` is somewhat redundant in the call and that it is legal to omit the return value, thus actually not updating the list.

A solution I like is to define a control struct for your list. At the moment, that just contains the head pointer:

```
struct list {
    struct elem *head;
};
```

Your functions that operate on the list then take a pointer to this structure as argument:

```
void del(struct list *list, int val) {
    struct elem* tmp = list->head;
    struct elem* prev = NULL;

    while (tmp != NULL) {
        if (tmp->val == val) {
            if (prev == NULL) {
                tmp = tmp->next;
                free(list->head);
                list->head = tmp;
            } else {
                prev->next = tmp->next;
                free(tmp);
                tmp = prev->next;
            }
        } else {
            prev = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

The `struct list` can have additional fields, for example the tail pointer for quick appending to the end. You could also keep track of the list length.

Comment: @pospeq You can make the changes inside the del function and return `struct elem *` then there is no need of double pointers. Keep your `head == list` here intact and retun head

Comment: @pospeq: I've added some other ways to achieve the same.

Comment: i particularly like the approach of having a list struct that knows about head.